# Remove css file from epub

Tags: android, epub

I'm using this [epublib](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib) in my project.

I'm trying to use my own custom styles, but they are in conflict with styles, that present in *.epub file. How can I remove this default css file with styles from *.epub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting definition of styles from head of html page.